# app.config file is not autogenerated or updated in VS2022 when adding a service refference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to add a SAP service reference to my new VS2022 project and the app.config file is not updated with the binding configurations for the service reference. I cannot add the bindings manually to my source code because the SAP service reference is not working properly. In older versions of VS is working just fine but I really need to upgrade to VS2022.

I modified the .csproj file and added the bellow rows but with no effect. I manually added the app.config file in the project, but still, when adding the service reference it is not modified with the settings that I need.

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<generatebindingredirectsoutputtype>true</generatebindingredirectsoutputtype>
```

Comment: Is this a console app or wpf or asp.net.core etc? please provide more information. Are you using net.4.8 or net core etc? you could share all relevant parts of the .csproj

Comment: This is windows form app( for the moment, later I want to modify to a web service). I am using .NET7 .

Comment: config files are no longer used in .NET5+.  If you want it back the old way then be sure to start the project with a template that has "(.NET Framework)" in its name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then how can I say programmability to one service reference that I have to call you HTTP and not HTTPS? in the past I was doing this from app.config binding area for that service reference.

Comment: I tried with the following but didn't worked.

Comment: BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("")